# como leer un token de un archivo json en VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, archivo, tokens, newtonsoft

Soy nuevo tratando con archivos json, he tratado de investigar mucho por mi cuenta como puedo leer un archivo json y extraer un valor y después modificarlo.
Lo que he hecho hasta ahora, es instalar el Newtonsoft.json en mis referencias y despues lo importo como:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
```

despues aplico este simple codigo:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("C:\Archivo.json"))
    MsgBox(json.SelectToken("objects").SelectToken("M/S/R/aaa.ext").SelectToken("hash"))
    End Sub
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error en el msgbox: *System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'*
No se que estoy haciendo mal.

Este es el contenido del json

```
{
  "objects": {   
    "M/S/R/aaa.ext": {
      "hash": "f86c466225dad2f32c90981485c1965671b3e8e6",
      "size": 591997
    },
    "M/S/R/bbb.ext": {
      "hash": "9cbed0e40296f68c61090c9b81816061e068a0ec",
      "size": 1071028
    },
    "M/S/R/ccc.ext": {
      "hash": "9b2a01e0d0456b8fbe33557fbc19d4fe342f94d6",
      "size": 2587419
    },
    "M/S/R/ddd.ext": {
      "hash": "d1eb3d2e39bf1f6289cfcbca44e1c9bb508b20f0",
      "size": 1286636
    },
    "M/S/R/fff.ext": {
      "hash": "ec8a2cbdf68b4e2136098ec33695e1c53625ddb8",
      "size": 1379756
    },
    "M/S/R/ggg.ext": {
      "hash": "f46c38e7d6d7b19d5d68aa18b557215738deb36a",
      "size": 1285938
    },
    "M/S/R/hhh.ext": {
      "hash": "83233451430516d839eaee855a2f789b8985d457",
      "size": 1430016
    },
    "M/S/R/iii.ext": {
      "hash": "6b44d0539073353b7a05330ccddc5735ba5efca4",
      "size": 663709
    },
    "M/S/R/jjj.ext": {
      "hash": "9ffb1791e8aba8f266a673abec1846c3bf8fb8cc",
      "size": 4838555
    },
    "M/S/R/kkk.ext": {
      "hash": "2c4f3f8f259dc782867727311fea30875ecc3917",
      "size": 1180789
    },
    "M/S/R/lll.ext": {
      "hash": "f34afa3ba5f756e90a1f61023bbe069ee8442608",
      "size": 1558180
    },
    "M/S/R/mmm.ext": {
      "hash": "876655d1691803f4cef17a6288d971285be79c6a",
      "size": 1845255
    },
    "M/S/R/nnn.ext": {
      "hash": "f685021d4f26d6b590bffb341908e25e92e18cef",
      "size": 1987588
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Intenta cambiar `SelectToken("M/S/R/aaa.ext")` por `SelectToken("['M/S/R/aaa.ext']")`

Comment: @braver me funcionó muchas gracias